# Transform lat, lng into x, y

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have coordinate system with x and y. Also I need to show there x,y point but I have coordinates latitude, longitude.

How can I transform latitude, longitude into x,y to show on x,y scale?

Comment: What software are you using? Do you have programming abilities?  What coordinate system do you want to convert to? You'll need to edit your question with these details.  Otherwise, it will likely be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import javax.measure.unit.NonSI;
import org.jscience.geography.coordinates.LatLong;
import org.jscience.geography.coordinates.UTM;
import org.jscience.geography.coordinates.crs.ReferenceEllipsoid;
```

This method makes the conversion in JAVA and return a Coordinate. Is easy to obtain X and Y from Coordinate

```
public static Coordinate Polar2UTM(double latitude, double longitude) {

    LatLong latlong = LatLong.valueOf(latitude, longitude, NonSI.DEGREE_ANGLE);

    UTM utm = UTM.latLongToUtm(latlong, ReferenceEllipsoid.WGS84);

    double cX = utm.getCoordinates()[0];
    double cY = utm.getCoordinates()[1];

    Coordinate coordenadas = new Coordinate(cX, cY);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to **convert (x, y) to/from (latitude and longitude)**

Have a look at the various code implementations on this page.

> https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator

Here are two JavaScript function examples...

```
mercator; //output mercator.x, mercator.y
latlon; //output latlon.lat, latlon.lon
```

You will need to have the measurements for your map.